# Replace only dlls when upgrading wix package

Tags: .net, wix, upgrade

I need to upgrade the existing application with new version without uninstalling the application. Meaning, i needs to only replace dll and application files, but do not want to uninstall whole application, only wants to change the version.

I had tried below snipped,

```
<Upgrade Id="$(var.UpgradeCode)">
  <UpgradeVersion  Minimum="1.0.0" IncludeMinimum="yes" OnlyDetect="yes" Maximum="2.3.0.76" IncludeMaximum="no" Property="PREVIOUSFOUND" />
</Upgrade>
```

Kept productId = "Guid" - constant, PackagedId = "GUID"-constant

```
 <?define UpgradeCode="7074527f-f87a-49be-8a51-952d34e1ed7f"?>
```

```
<MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." AllowDowngrades="no" AllowSameVersionUpgrades="yes" />
<MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />

<Upgrade Id="$(var.UpgradeCode)">
  <UpgradeVersion  Minimum="1.0.0" IncludeMinimum="yes" OnlyDetect="yes" Maximum="2.3.0.76" IncludeMaximum="no" Property="PREVIOUSFOUND" />
</Upgrade>
```

Please let me know, how can we achieve the updating files without uninstalling whole existing files.

Getting below error:
Another version of this product is already installed.

Answer (score 0):

Constant ProductCode means you want a "minor upgrade" so the Upgrade and MajorUprade elements are not in play. Use `/f` for minor upgrade.

That said, a late major upgrade would probably give you what you want as well.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you please let me know where do we need to use /f in .wxs file? and pls refer some documentation links if possible.

Comment: also, getting "Another version of this product is already installed." when i am keeping the product id constant. Not able to proceed

Comment: a late major upgrade - are you saying to use Before
InstallFinalize for RemoveExistingProducts?

Comment: Yeah, you'll want to read the MSI SDK documentation on MSDN about the different upgrades and how to initiate a minor upgrade using the /f switch to msiexec.exe